# useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component, but it's already used in Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I need a help to get rid of this error, `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

As far as I can tell from my code, `useNavigate()` is called in the function `handleSubmit()`, which is called  in the `<form>` component, which is in the `<Route>` component. So I don't understand why I am getting this error. Can somebody navigate me to the solution? Thank you

My "react-router-dom" version is 6.8.1.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import SignIn from './SignIn';
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import TravelPlan from './TravelPlan';

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [destination, setDestination] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      destination: destination,
    };
    const response = await axios.post('/travel', data);
    navigate("/travelplan");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar loggedIn={loggedIn} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} handleSignin={handleSignin} />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      Destination:
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        value={destination}
                        onChange={(e) => setDestination(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            }>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn handleSignin={handleSignin} />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/travelplan" element={<TravelPlan />} />
          </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `useNavigate` is **called** in the second line of the component. Its **return value** is called in the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `useNavigate` and `Router` in the same component. `useNavigate` should be in a lower component from where `Router` is defined.

Just move  **`<BrowserRouter>`**   from `App.js` to the `index.js` .

**like this (index.js) :**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```